# How to initialize an interface that contains a sub interface

Tags: angular, typescript

A variable that is in a sub interface is undefined. How can I initialize all the variables of an interface including sub interfaces.

I tried to use extends, but it still did not work.

Interface

```
export interface UserModel {

        username?: any;
        email?: any;
        first_name?: any;
        last_name?: any;
        profile?: ProfileModel;

}

interface ProfileModel {

        nome_empresa?: any;
        cnpj?: any;
}
```

Component

```
export class PerfilComponent implements OnInit {

  user = <UserModel>{};

  constructor(private perfil: PerfilService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.perfil.get().subscribe((perfil) => {
      this.user = perfil;
    })

  }
```

In Template

PerfilComponent.html:61 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nome_empresa' of undefined

PerfilComponent.html:61 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'cnpj' of undefined

Comment: It is not necessary? I thought it would be exported automatically.

Comment: @zgue those are runtime errors, they have nothing to do with interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you're getting in `prefil`.
you can do this:

```
this.perfil.get().subscribe((perfil) => {
    this.user = Object.assign({}, { profile: {} }, perfil);
});
```

Just to make sure that `this.user.profile` is not `undefined`.

---

#### Edit

You're probably getting that error even before making the request, so it should also be:

```
export class PerfilComponent implements OnInit {
    user = <UserModel> { profile: {} };

    ...
}
```

Comment: Check my revised answer

Comment: Do I need to do this every time an intereface has other properties?

Comment: It's not related to interfaces, you're getting a runtime error in javascript. You need to make sure that you're not trying to access properties of objects which are `undefined`.  The same would have happened if you'd try to do `this.user.username.length` if `this.user.username` is `undefined`.